# C# Asp.net MVC on the complier it says error code "CS1061"

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

The tutorial I'm (was) following, they have an option to select "using Microsoft entity framework" but for me, it does not show that potential fix, any advice would be much appreciated.

```
 services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<NewContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

[Error message screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZyuH.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project needs to have the entity framework libraries referenced.

Try adding the "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" nuget package to your project.
Then add the using directive.

Comment: I already have it downloaded at the start of the project

Comment: what do you mean by "downloaded"? Is it shown in your project references?

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry - you were right yes what I did was I had "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" not "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" now I just installed it and it fixed the issue thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome. Please consider marking this as answer.